# pop up message on success full submit

Tags: javascript, php

i am creating a blog posting page for practice.
1) i want a pop up window 'javascript' on success full data submitting to phpmyadmin.
2) same on failure a popup window.

3)where exactly we should close the mysqli connection mysqli_close(); in a isset codding.

i have tried all onclick, onsubmit, two function on one onclick but all in vain
reasons: two javascripts function were not working on one button.
         while onsubmit code typed the popup window appears but data does not success fully submits to phpmyadmin.

```
<html>

                        <head>
                                <title>
                                </title>
                        </head>

        <link href="blogsup-main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="blogsup.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

                        <body onload="refresh();">

                                    <center>
                                            <form method="post">
```

Name

Category

```
                                                   <option>Education</option>
                                                    <option>Society</option>
                                                    <option>Politics</option>
                                                    <option>Business</option>
                                                    <option>IT</option>
                                                    <option>Book</option>
                                                    <option>Other</option>
```

Heading

Sub heading *optional

Blog

<sup>*</sup>Send Email

```
                                            </form>
                                    </center>





                    <div id="popupdiv" class="popup-area">


                    <div class="popup-content">

                        <span class="close">&times;</span>



                        <center>
```

**Blog Created Success Fully!
pending approval.**

Proceed

```
                        </center>


                    </div>

                    </div>










                        </body>

                </html>







                    <?php

                                $user='root';
                                $password='';
                                $db='blogsup';



                        $con=mysqli_connect('localhost',$user,$password,$db);
                        mysqli_select_db($con,$db);


                                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){



                                    $bloggername=$_POST['bloggername'];
                                    $category=$_POST['category'];
                                    $heading=$_POST['heading'];
                                    $subheading=$_POST['subheading'];
                                    $textarea=$_POST['textarea'];



                                    $que="insert into blogposting (bloggername,category,heading,subheading,blogdate,blog) values ('$bloggername','$category','$heading ','$subheading', now(),'$textarea')";
                                    $run=mysqli_query($con,$que);


                                    if($run){


                            echo '<script type="text/javascript">

                        var popupdiv = document.getElementById("popupdiv");
                        popupdiv.style.display = "block";
                        return false;

                                    </script>';


                                    }   else{
                                                echo"Failed";

                                        }
                                }

                                mysqli_close($con);


                    ?>



        <script type="text/javascript">     


                    var nametextbox = document.getElementById('nametextbox');
                    var heading= document.getElementById('heading');
                    var blog = document.getElementById('blog');
                    var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];






                function refresh(){
                    nametextbox.value='';
                    heading.value='';
                    subheading.value='';
                    blog.value='';

                }
                        span.onclick = function() {
                            popupdiv.style.display = "none";
                            nametextbox.value='';
                            heading.value='';
                            subheading.value='';
                            blog.value='';
                            message.innerHTML = '';

                        }




        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form there is no success or failure.You shouldn't add php and html and js code in the same page.Add the php code to php file which will be your action
e.g

```
<form action="anyfile.php" method="post">
```

In the php file add your business logic, like connect to db, execute queries and close the db connection.when the insert query is executed without errors then send a redirect back (yourMainPage?message='ok') to show a successful message like

```
<?php if(isset($_GET('message') == 'ok'){ ?>
<p>Data successfully inserted</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Also, your code should be more tidy. Hope i helped.

Comment: on action how the user will receive the message the blog is pending approval and the blog has been created success fully? i  have seen that kind of stuff on voting sites like my laureus.com

Comment: you should have a column in db for approval.And check this using query if it's approved then send message 'ok' if not approved send message for pending